# git svn clone does not grab a branch not in stdlayout

Tags: clone, git-svn

I have a svn folder structure like this:

mainFolder
|_ trunk
|_ branches
|_ tags
|_ accidentallyCreatedBranch

Now I want to grab the complete svn repo and convert it to a git repo. For this my commandline is as follows:

```
git svn clone --trunk=/trunk --branches=/accidentallyCreatedBranch --branches=/branches --tags=/tags -A ~/authorsFile http://svn.url.loc/svn/repository destFolder/
```

git svn works perfect, but my accidentallyCreatedBranch is not in the target git repo.

From the manpage side there are no restrictions to give more than one --branches options.

What do I am wrong?

After cloning the svn repo into a git repo even the config references this branch:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://svn.url.loc/svn/repository
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = accidentallyCreatedBranch/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
[svn]
    authorsfile = /home/migration/authors
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards
Daimonion